# How can I set the mark color in PGFPLOTS legend?

Tags: pgfplots

**Updated:** I want to set the color of the mark in the legend to a specific value, but don't know how. The reason for that is that I don't want one legendentry per color (that would be six colors in the MWE below), but one legendentry per "green" and one per "blue".

Here's a litte MWE to demonstrate. I have put a non-working `mark color=XXX` as addlegendentry option to show what I wanted to do.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents,tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic,draw opacity=0,mark size=3,%
   scatter/classes={ %
      a={mark=*,fill=Green},%
      b={mark=*,fill=ForestGreen},%
      c={mark=*,fill=OliveGreen},%
      d={mark=*,fill=Cyan},%
      e={mark=*,fill=TealBlue},%
      f={mark=*,fill=SkyBlue}%
}}}

\begin{filecontents}{timings.txt}
12   13    2     8    0.223    2.23949e+06    a
13   15    4     8    0.483    2.83788e+11    a
 6    7    1     3    0.021    64             b
22   29   10    13    0.689    3.21053e+10    b
22   29   10    13    0.693    3.21053e+10    c
11   14    6    15    0.205    1.65888e+06    c
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{timings2.txt}
12   13   26   926   10.966    2.94773e+10   d
13   15  459  4034  317.309    1.02249e+16   d
 6    7    4     5    0.029    810           e
22   29  716   841   46.686    2.48052e+15   e
22   29  716   841   46.708    2.48052e+15   f
11   14   43    81    1.056    1.24003e+09   f
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
\addplot[mystyle] table[x index=5, y index=4, meta index=6] {timings.txt};
\addplot[mystyle] table[x index=5, y index=4, meta index=6] {timings2.txt};
\addlegendentry[mark color=red]{foo}
\addlegendentry[mark color=black]{bar}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The optional argument of `\addlegendentry` is for the **text** of the legend entry and not for the legend symbol. So to help you it would be nice if you could edit your question and state a more real MWE, i.e. you mentioned using `meta index` for the plots which you don't use in your MWE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And of course your MWE doesn't have any marks at all now. Neither in the plots nor in the legend ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow: Thanks for your comment, I have updated the MWE to (almost) reflect the real situation.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\addlegendimage` I suppose.

[image: legend with red and black dot]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic,draw opacity=0,mark size=3,%
   scatter/classes={ %
      a={mark=*,fill=Green},%
      b={mark=*,fill=ForestGreen},%
      c={mark=*,fill=OliveGreen},%
      d={mark=*,fill=Cyan},%
      e={mark=*,fill=TealBlue},%
      f={mark=*,fill=SkyBlue}%
}}}

\begin{filecontents}{timings.txt}
12   13    2     8    0.223    2.23949e+06    a
13   15    4     8    0.483    2.83788e+11    a
 6    7    1     3    0.021    64             b
22   29   10    13    0.689    3.21053e+10    b
22   29   10    13    0.693    3.21053e+10    c
11   14    6    15    0.205    1.65888e+06    c
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{timings2.txt}
12   13   26   926   10.966    2.94773e+10   d
13   15  459  4034  317.309    1.02249e+16   d
 6    7    4     5    0.029    810           e
22   29  716   841   46.686    2.48052e+15   e
22   29  716   841   46.708    2.48052e+15   f
11   14   43    81    1.056    1.24003e+09   f
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
\addlegendimage{mark=*,red,only marks,mark size=3}
\addlegendimage{mark=*,black,only marks,mark size=3}

\addplot[mystyle] table[x index=5, y index=4, meta index=6] {timings.txt};
\addplot[mystyle] table[x index=5, y index=4, meta index=6] {timings2.txt};
\addlegendentry{foo}
\addlegendentry{bar}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! The thing that makes the difference for me was that one has to put *both* `\addlegendimage` settings before the `\addplot` directives.

Comment: @cxxl That, or you can add `forget plot` to the `\addplot` options. (`\addplot[mystyle,forget plot] ..`).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative of adding `\addlegendimage` commands you could also state some dummy scatter classes *before* your real use scatter classes. (Also you can simplify your code a bit.) For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
    \begin{filecontents}{timings.txt}
        12   13    2     8    0.223    2.23949e+06    a
        13   15    4     8    0.483    2.83788e+11    a
         6    7    1     3    0.021    64             b
        22   29   10    13    0.689    3.21053e+10    b
        22   29   10    13    0.693    3.21053e+10    c
        11   14    6    15    0.205    1.65888e+06    c
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{timings2.txt}
        12   13   26   926   10.966    2.94773e+10   d
        13   15  459  4034  317.309    1.02249e+16   d
         6    7    4     5    0.029    810           e
        22   29  716   841   46.686    2.48052e+15   e
        22   29  716   841   46.708    2.48052e+15   f
        11   14   43    81    1.056    1.24003e+09   f
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        only marks,
        mark size=3,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
            % for the legend entries (only)
            dummy1={mark=*,green},
            dummy2={mark=*,blue},
            % the real scatter classes
            a={mark=*,Green},
            b={mark=*,ForestGreen},
            c={mark=*,OliveGreen},
            d={mark=*,Cyan},
            e={mark=*,TealBlue},
            f={mark=*,SkyBlue}
        },
        table/x index=5,
        table/y index=4,
        table/meta index=6,
    ]
        \addplot [scatter] table {timings.txt};
        \addplot [scatter] table {timings2.txt};
        \legend{
            foo,
            bar,
        }
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is just to overwrite the line drawn by pgfplots. All one has to do is to give the nodes in the legend a name and then to draw the line in whatever color. I made the line a bit thicker, but this is not necessary, one could also use `double` or whatever.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
\addplot[domain=1:10^39,green] {x^( 0.09761512598518318 ) * 10^( -1.1943157065805068 ) };
\addplot[domain=1:10^39,blue] {x^( 0.26304620518434785 ) * 10^( -2.117101843033601 ) };
\addlegendentry[name=foo]{\scriptsize foo}
\addlegendentry[name=bar]{\scriptsize bar}
\end{loglogaxis}
\draw[red,thick] (foo) -- ++(-0.9cm,0);
\draw[black,thick] (bar) -- ++(-0.9cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]